# What is the recommended command line argument syntax?

Tags: bash, syntax, command-line-arguments

I am writing a executable script(perl) that takes arguments from the command line. Here is some different syntaxs, I can think of:

1. `myPerlScript 10 42`
2. `myPerlScript myarg1=10 myarg2=42`
3. `myPerlScript -myarg1=10 -myarg2=42`
4. `myPerlScript myarg1 10 myarg2 42`
5. `myPerlScript -myarg1 10 -myarg2 42`

I do not like option 1. as it is not possible to give the arguments in arbitrary order, or skip the arguments to rely on default values. I would also like to give 2(or 3,...) dimensional arguments. Here are some examples again:

1. `myPerlScript myarg 10x20`
2. `myPerlScript myarg=10x20`
3. `myPerlScript -myarg 10x20`
4. `myPerlScript -myarg=10x20`
5. `myPerlScript -myarg=10 20`
6. `myPerlScript -myarg=10,20`

What is *the* recommended syntax? or what would you recommend? and does it depend on situations and/or what the script is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about perl, but in ruby world (and the rest of unix that I can observe) this seems to be the most accepted idiom:

```
myPerlScript --myarg1 10 --myarg2 42
```

There's a difference between single and double dash. Some commands have two forms: long (full command name) and short (a single letter, for brevity). Double dash is for long form, single - for short one. Real life example:

```
mysql --user root
mysql -u root
```

I'd say that using single dash with long form will surprise people. Don't do that :)

And I also can recommend this excellent book: [Building awesome command-line applications in Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/dccar/build-awesome-command-line-applications-in-ruby). Although it will be of less value to you, because it's in ruby, not perl.

Comment: uhhhh. I did not think of two dashes. I have not seen that often. Is one dash reserved for pure bash? Do you also have opinion on the 2D case?

Comment: 2D is no different. I'd write it as `myscript --myarg 10x20`

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: well, as I said, it's likely that in perl world you have different idioms. My answer is about what I observe in my everyday life and read in books.

Comment: Thaks --great:o) tips. I am convinced that this is also the way in perl.

Comment: Single hyphen with a single-character option conforms to the POSIX command-line standard and is supported by the `getopts` program (see `man getopts`).  *Long options* (two hyphens and multiple character options) are non-standard but used extensively in GNU utilities.  Perl has at least three different getopts modules.